# How the python interpreter receives and outputs data?

Tags: python, c, io, stdout, stdin

What happens when I write `print('Something')`?
Does the interpreter work directly with the system I / O means, or does it use some kind of system API, which gives information that something needs to be displayed in the console?

Likewise for input. If I call the `input()` function, then it is the python interpreter itself that will read the input values, or it will again delegate this work to some system API, which will wrap the input.

I know that python is written in C language (at least its main implementation). It turns out that it is the C language inside the interpreter that is responsible for the input / output?

All my attempts to find an answer come down to articles where they tell me that in `input()` you need to press a button from the keyboard, and the `print()` function will print something in the console. I already know this, I want to know what is happening at the level below.

Comment: Python is open source, so the source code is available to look at. That might be a bit overwhelming for a beginner though, especially one that doesn't know C that well. So please tell us, *why* are you wondering this? Do you have an underlying problem that you think this knowledge will solve? Then ask about that directly instead. Or is it just plain curiosity? Curiosity isn't wrong, but please state so in your question. And even if it's just for curiosity, why do you want to know? Being a good Python programmer doesn't mean you need those details.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I can dig into the source code and find this data there, but my level of expertise in reading source codes in C is 0, I asked the question in the hope that someone had already opened this 'Pandora's Box' and knows the answer.
Curiosity drives me. I know that all scripting languages ​​don't have their own input and output. And I wanted to find out what this also applies to the Python language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `print('Something')`, here's what happens at a lower level:

1. **Python Interpreter:** The Python interpreter is responsible for executing your code line by line.
2. **print() Function:** When the interpreter encounters the `print('Something')` statement, it first evaluates the expression within the parentheses, which is just a string in this case, *'Something'*.
3. **System Call:** The Python interpreter uses a system call to communicate with the operating system or the environment it is running in (e.g., a console or terminal). The system call is an interface provided by the operating system to access various low-level functions, including input/output operations.
4. **System API:** The system call is handled by a system API. This API is part of the operating system and allows the Python interpreter to interact with the underlying I/O facilities of the system. It provides a way for the Python interpreter to communicate with the console or terminal and display the text 'Something'.
5. **Display:** Finally, the text *'Something'* is displayed in the console or terminal where you are running the Python program.

Similarly, when you use `input()`:

1. **Python Interpreter:** The Python interpreter is executing your code.
2. **input() Function:** When the interpreter encounters `input()`, it pauses
   the program's execution and waits for the user to input some text.
3. **System API:** The interpreter uses a system API to access the
   underlying I/O facilities of the system and wait for the user to
   provide input.
4. **User Input:** The system API captures the user's input from the
   console or terminal and passes it back to the Python interpreter.
5. **Continue Execution:** The Python interpreter resumes execution with
   the input provided by the user, and you can assign it to a variable
   or use it in your program as needed.

> So, in summary, when you interact with the Python interpreter using
> functions like print() and input(), the interpreter itself relies on
> system APIs provided by the operating system to handle the actual
> input and output operations. This abstraction allows Python to work
> seamlessly across different platforms and environments.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help you. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.